# $\exists \implies \forall$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I want to see some example theorem, when existence implies universality, so $\exists \implies \forall$ is true.

I think *matematical induction* is a related technique, but I just don't see that induction covers the whole topic. On the other hand, there are some situation, when existence implies that the statemant is true for "some" element. For example in the *fundamental theorem of algebra* the existence of *one* root is equivalent of the existence of exactly *n* roots.

So I expect some example. Thanks.

Comment: Take any statement known to be true, put a sterile universal quantification behind it and make this new statement the consequent of the implication.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes here. It is an *interesting* problem (trivial examples aside), so although open-ended I see no issue with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This's an example from linear algebra:

Let $f\colon\Bbb R^n\rightarrow R^n$ a linear transformation.

these statements are equivalent

- $f$ is orthogonal
- $f$ maps **an** orthonormal basis to an orthonormal basis
- $f$ maps **every** orthonormal basis to an orthonormal basis

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple but widely used theorem.

For any polynomial $p$ of degree $n$:

$\exists( n+1 \text{ distinct values for }x )( p(x) = 0 ) \Rightarrow \forall x( p(x) = 0 )$

Answer (score 1):

$\exists n \in \mathbb{Z} ( 2n=1 ) \Rightarrow \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} ( 2n=1 )$

Answer (score 0):

For a homogeneous DE $y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y=0$ on some interval $J$, Let $y_1,y_2$ be two solutions. We have the Wronskian $W(y_1,y_2)(x) = y_1y_2' - y_2y_1'$. Then it is a result of Abel's identity that if $\exists x \in J $ such that $W(y_1,y_2)(x) =0 \implies \forall x\in J$ we have $W(y_1,y_2)(x) =0$.